# I still get categorical variables after using OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, encoding, one-hot-encoding

I have three columns in this range ('gender', 'Age, 'AnnualIncome'),I used:

`x = dataset.iloc [:, 1:-1].values`
and I am sure this covers all three columns mentioned above.

**I have two problems:**

1- I am using the code below to encode the column 'Genre', after execution I still see the categorical data

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("encoder", OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder = "passthrough")
x = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))
```

and the output still has 'Male' and 'Female' values:

```bash
[[0.0 1.0 0.0 ... 0.0 'Male' 15]
[1.0 0.0 1.0 ... 0.0 'Male' 15]
[1.0 0.0 1.0 ... 0.0 'Female' 16]
...
[1.0 0.0 1.0 ... 0.0 'Male' 126]
[1.0 0.0 1.0 ... 0.0 'Male' 137]
[1.0 0.0 1.0 ... 0.0 'Male' 137]]
```

2- second problem is that the output above, did not include my third column in the dataset even though it is included in the range I specified for x.

Do you have any idea why this might be happening?